# Need to cure my regular expression from greedy

Tags: regex

I have an expression

```
^(((\d{1,2}))|((\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}))|((\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})))(;?)$
```

to validate a text line like these:

```
9
99
99.9
99.99
99.99.9
99.99.99
```

Now I need to validate all these possible variants for `;`-separated text

When I use an expression:

```
^(((((\d{1,2}))|((\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}))|((\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})))(;?))+?)$
```

It becomes greedy and allows more than 2 digits.

Sorry guys, I need to add some explanations. This is an example of all possible matches

```
9;99;99.9;99.99;99.99.9;99.99.99
```

Comment: `(((((`... Nice, but totally redundant :P

Comment: good, but sometimes, regular exps are not good. just split your string by `;` and do first task, that you ask us about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't caused by greedy matching, but by the fact that you allow the separating semicolon only optionally. I'd try something like (given `dotted_number` is regex that matches your original single value, no semicolon)

```
^(dotted_number;)*dotted_number;?$
```

In the end, it would look like

```
^((\d{1,2}\.){0,2}(\d{1,2});)*(\d{1,2}\.){0,2}(\d{1,2});?$
```

Or you could perenthesize it the other way around, which may be slightly faster

```
^dotted_number(;dotted_number)*;?$
```

Even this works:

```
egrep '^(([[:digit:]]{1,2}\.){0,2}[[:digit:]]{1,2}(;|;?$))+$'
```

Comment: it's good, but it is more simple and good to split string by `;`, you know. regexps has a finite automata mechanizm inside, so, don't play with it too much ;)

Comment: @loldop: while I agree with the suggestion to split, I object to the suggestion that regexp shouldn't be played with too much. Finite automata seem quite powerful, yet pretty tame beasts to me. (although I'm not 100% sure every implementation of RE use finite automata internally).

Answer (score 2):

use this regex `^\d{1,2}(\.|;\d{1,2})*$`

or

set repeat count `^\d{1,2}(\.|;\d{1,2})`**{0,2}**`$`

Comment: Where are the semicolons for semicolon-separated-data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
^(\d{1,2})(;(\d{1,2})){0,2}$
```

It accepts described inputs with `;` separator.

If you want to test `.` separator, just change `;` with `\.`:

```
^(\d{1,2})(\.(\d{1,2})){0,2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problematic regex allows more than two digits because the first option,

```
((\d{1,2}))
```

followed by a `+` at the end matches any number of digits effectively.

Answer (score 1):

maybe i am wrong, but you need something like this:

```
^((\d)\2?)(?:[.](?:\1|\2))*$
```

change `*` to whatever you want:) like `{0,2}` or something else to match yours patterns.

What i do here?

i just use `\2 \1` - it is a groups, that already matched in regex :)

`99.99.99`

`\1` is outer brackets, so it match first `99` = `^(    (\d)\2?   )...`

`\2` is inner brackets, so it match `9`  =  `( \d )\2?`

Comment: That won't match eg. `12.34`, which is accepted by the OP's original regexp.

Comment: it's so strange, because OP ask about text with only one `9`